# How to append a whole HTML collection

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, append

how do I append an HTML collection that I want to add in a specific amount of time depending on a for loop length?

here is my JS code

```
            function createDiv() {


                    const numberLine = [1, 2, 3, 4];

                    for (i = 0; i < numberLine.length; i++) {
                        const numberTextContent = document.getElementById('numberTextContent');

                        numberTextContent.textContent = numberLine[i];


                        const jobPostCollection = ' <div class="jobContainer col-md-6"> \
                        <div class="jobName"> \
                        <h1 class="text-center" id="numberTextContent"></h1> \
                        </div> \
                        </div> \
                        </div>';

                        const jobPosting = document.getElementById('jobPosting');

                        jobPosting.appendChild(jobPostCollection);




                    }




            }
```

I am trying to have it where the HTML collection of `jobContainer` show in the amount of times in correlation to the `numberLine` length.

Here is my HTML code

```
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="jobPosting">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="button">BUTTON</button>
</div>
```

Comment: *jobPostCollection* is not an [HTML collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), it's just a string. You can concatenate it *n* times and insert it once as *innerHTML*.

Comment: how would I be able to concatenate it n times and have it append to the number of times that I want it to ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but maybe you can try this way to make it easier.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="jobPosting">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="button" onclick="createDiv();">BUTTON</button>
</div>
<script>
```

JS:

```
function createDiv() {

    h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.innerHTML = "111"  // if you don't need, just remove
    h1.setAttribute("id",'1111');  //set id, also can change to class

    var jobPosting  = document.getElementById('jobPosting');
    jobPosting.appendChild(h1);

}
```